# Adding columns to multiple dataframes via loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have several dataframes and would like to add columns with a loop. At the moment the code looks like this:

```
FR1$MONTH<-'2015-01'
FR2$MONTH<-'2015-02'
FR3$MONTH<-'2015-03'
FR4$MONTH<-'2015-04'
```

I have tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:12) {
   assign(paste("FR",i,$,"MONTH",sep=""),paste("2015-",i,sep=""))

}
```

Unfortunatly it doesnt work.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my try, or even better: How to do this right as I suspect a loop isnt the best solution.

Comment: the question is answerable, but I would stop this bad R coding approach of spreading lots of dataframes in the global envrionnment instead of putting them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue that would throw you an error is that the '$' should be within quotes within the first paste() call.

I would try, however:

`eval(parse(text = paste0("FR", i, "$MONTH <- 2015-", i)))`

within your loop.  And you may want to use an `ifelse()` to get the 0 in the month when you need it.

And I second Colonel's comment about keeping your data.frames within some other data structure.

Comment: Thanks. The eval(parse()) worked. After that I tried it by putting the frames into a list. You are right, that seems like the much better solution. Thanks!